# How to train gpt2 model to learn from the training text I have given?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, training-data, huggingface, gpt-2, fine-tuning

I'm trying to train and fine tune my gpt2 model with my own sample training document. I'm using the code similar to this: https://www.kaggle.com/code/changyeop/how-to-fine-tune-gpt-2-for-beginners . But the text generated is not related to any text in my training document. Is there any solution on how to approach this?